# Is it possible to get a Taiwan tourist visa in Shanghai for Sri Lankans?

Tags: tourist-visas, taiwan, sri-lankan-citizens

I'm a Sri Lankan passport holder looking for advices to apply for Taiwan tourist visa in Shanghai. Since there is no Taiwan embassy in Sri Lanka, normally Sri Lankans go to India or Singapore to get Taiwan visas. I'm frequently flying to China, hence considering about applying it in Shanghai.

Comment: Probably not. Beijing and Taipei do not recognize each other and thus don't have representative offices; Taiwan Entry Permit is handled by travel agencies in mainland China. However, I believe they are only authorized to handle applications for the Taiwan Entry Permit for Mainland Residents, not regular visas.